# Multiple Executions of SSIS Package Running Child Packages in Parallel Variable Issue

Tags: powershell, ssis, parallel-processing, guid

Apologies for the long title!

I've got an SSIS Package with 6 parallel packages that execute inside it. These packages get passed a guid from the parent and then use this to log into a table their progress. 
This setup works fine when executed alone: in the IDE, from the SSISDB and called from Powershell (using the SSISDB). However, when more than 1 instance of this package is executed from the SSISDB (called from Powershell) I get invalid format errors from the child packages for the guid as they try to parse it. I've created logs and script tasks to output the guid as it gets passed through and it seems to be null! Anyone got any ideas? This doesn't happen consistently every time, and not always the same package so it has to be something to do with executing the parent packages in parallel?

Thanks for you help in advance